# How to handle unavailable texlive packages on el7

Tags: yum, latex

I am on SL7 (EL7), and after upgrading from 6, I now get the error

```
! LaTeX Error: File `lineno.sty' not found.
```

I don't remember how I made that package available in 6. I have spent a while searching for a solution, but this package does not appear to be available from standard repositories, and I have not found a clear description on the best way to proceed. I realize I could download from ctan. But I am wondering if there is a better (staying with yum) way to handle this and other missing texlive packages.

Answer (score 1):

You should have mentioned that you downloaded it through your distro's package manager instead of installing tex live on its own (which I personally recommend)  so it would manage its updates and tex packages through its own package manager called **tlmgr**. There you could search for the package. Other than that TeX Live has no package auto-dl feature on its own (yet?), see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110501/auto-package-download-for-texlive

Comment: I thought I did mention it (the post is tagged with "yum", and I wrote "staying within yum"), although I could have been more clear. But I don't really see this as an answer. Installing texlive on its own, outside of package management seems like a pretty drastic solution to a single missing package, and you don't really provide any arguments for why that is the best way, you only say that you personally recommend doing so.

Comment: True, I didn't really list the advantages, my bad.
So for one you are more up-to-date using it, which might be especially useful when using XeTeX or LuaTeX. Then you can customize your installation in a more fine-grained, even installing just the packages you need. And lastly it's not "outside package management", it's just using a different package manager just like you might also do with programming languages (environments) like Python, Ruby or Haskell.

Comment: Also you find missing packages easier, also see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28533.